# Skip certificate validation in IIB

Tags: ssl, https, ibm-integration-bus

I am using HTTPRequest node to make requests using TLS. Is there a way to skip certificate validation (checking the certificate chain, the expiration date) with standard IIB settings? I know this is risky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do this kind of things, there is a lot of workaround, but they are not that easy and quite horrible. I would suggest you to use a JavaCompute Node, using unix curl/wget commands for example (if running on Unix), or any other solution that is working on Java.

But I can confirm, you cannot use the default IIB nodes (like HTTPRequest) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/314605/certificate-expired-skip-checking-external-server.html), you have to handle the exception yourself because IBM will not provide you a flag since it is a major security risk.

Comment: thanks, still, if I handle the exception, I won't be able to make the request, which was my goal. However, in this case we chose not to skip the validation as it is risky